# How I can send POST request with data from table?

Tags: java, html, forms, thymeleaf

I want to send POST request with data which is stored in a HTML table. I'm using thymleaf.

I tried to send GET request with data for build table, but I didn't get the response data from the table while using the POST request.

**What is the problem?**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Smoke Tests</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${ankiCardsList}">
    <table border="1px">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Word</th>
            <th>Transcription</th>
            <th>Translate</th>
            <th>Eng Example</th>
            <th>Rus Example</th>
            <th>Sound</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="ankiCard : ${ankiCards}">
            <td th:text="${ankiCard.word}"></td>
            <td th:text="${ankiCard.transcription}"></td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input th:value="${ankiCard.translation}"/>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <select>
                        <option th:each="example : ${ankiCard.examples}">
                            <p th:text="${example.engExample}"></p>
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </td>

            <td>
                <label>
                    <select>
                        <option th:each="example : ${ankiCard.examples}">
                            <p th:text="${example.rusExample}"></p>
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td th:text="${ankiCard.soundURL}"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

model AnkiCardDto

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AnkiCardDto {
    private String word;
    private String transcription;
    private String translation;
    private List<Examples> examples;
    private String soundURL;
}
```

DTO for response data from table

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AnkiCardsList {
    private List<AnkiCardDto> ankiCards = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

All code you look there:
https://github.com/Teemitze/ankiFIll2

Thanks, for help friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to send a post request using the JS code below.

```
function AnkiCard(word, transcription, translation, examples, soundURL) {
            this.word = word;
            this.transcription = transcription;
            this.translation = translation;
            this.examples = examples;
            this.soundURL = soundURL;
        }

        function Examples(engExample, rusExample) {
            this.engExample = engExample;
            this.rusExample = rusExample;
        }


        function sendTable() {
            let cells = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            let ankiCards = [];

            for (let i = 1; i < cells.length; i++) {
                let word = cells[i].getElementsByTagName("td").item(0).innerText;
                let transcription = cells[i].getElementsByTagName("td").item(1).innerText;
                let translation = cells[i].getElementsByTagName("td").item(2).getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).value;
                let engExample = cells[i].getElementsByTagName("td").item(3).getElementsByTagName("option");
                let selectEngExample = findSelectExample(engExample);

                let rusExamples = cells[i].getElementsByTagName("td").item(4).getElementsByTagName("option");
                let selectRusExample = findSelectExample(rusExamples);

                let examples = new Examples(selectEngExample, selectRusExample);


                let soundURL = cells[i].getElementsByTagName("td").item(5).innerText;

                const ankiCard = new AnkiCard(word, transcription, translation, examples, soundURL);

                console.log(translation);

                ankiCards.push(ankiCard);

                console.log(JSON.stringify(ankiCard));
            }

            sendRequest(ankiCards)

        }

        function findSelectExample(examples) {
            for (let i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
                if (examples[i].selected === true) {
                    return examples[i].innerText;
                }
            }
        }

        function sendRequest(ankiCards) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var body = JSON.stringify(ankiCards);

            xhr.open("POST", '/save', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            xhr.send(body);
        }
```